# How to select multiple cells of QTableWidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am trying to pre-select multiple "individual values (or cells some would like to call em)" from the QTableWidget and I don't seem to be able to find the right method. I have tried setRangeSelect,selectRow & selectColumn, and none of the methods works.

Looking for some help. (Please see the test method for what I am trying to do)

```py
import sys
import json
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.Qt import QTableWidgetItem, QAbstractItemView

class Demo(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowTracker = []
        self.initUI()
        self.initQTableWidget()

    def initUI(self):       
        self.resize(600, 600)
        # populate some data
        self.rows = [['a1','b1', 'c1'], ['a2','b2','c2'], ['a3','b3','c3'], ['a4','b4','c4'], ['a5','b5','c5']]

        self.btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.move(50, 250)
        self.btn.resize(150, 40)
        self.btn.setText('Check')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.test)

    def initQTableWidget(self):
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.resize(self.width(), self.height()-400)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.rows))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(self.rows[0]))

        # here we will change row selection behavior to multiselection
        self.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)

        for row in enumerate(self.rows):
            # print(row)
            for col in enumerate(row[1]):
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setText(col[1])
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col[0], item)

    def test(self):
        # print(dir(self.tableWidget))
        self.tableWidget.select('<2nd row>', '<1st column>')

        self.tableWidget.select('<3nd row>', '<2nd column>')
        # self.tableWidget.setRangeSelect()

app =QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = Demo()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following methods:

1. The [`setSelected()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setSelected) method of [`QtableWidgetItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html):

```py
self.tableWidget.item(1, 0).setSelected(True)
self.tableWidget.item(2, 1).setSelected(True)
```

2. The [`select()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#select) method of [`QItemSelectionModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html):

```
model = self.tableWidget.model()
selection_model = self.tableWidget.selectionModel()
selection_model.select(model.index(1, 0), QItemSelectionModel.Select)
selection_model.select(model.index(2, 1), QItemSelectionModel.Select)
```

The second method is general for all views that inherit from [`QAbstractItemView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html), and the first method is just a wrapper that makes [`QTableWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) of the second method.